# How to extract all (including int and float) numerical values in a string column in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I have a table `Table_1` on Google BigQuery which includes a string column `str_column`. I would like to write a SQL query (compatible with Google BigQuery) to extract all numerical values in `str_column` and append them as new numerical columns to `Table_1`. For example, if `str_column` includes `first measurement is 22 and the other is 2.5`; I need to extract 22 and 2.5 and save them under new columns `numerical_val_1` and `numerical_val_2`. The number of new numerical columns should ideally be equal to the maximum number of numerical values in `str_column`, but if that'd be too complex, extracting the first 2 numerical values in `str_column` (and therefore 2 new columns) would be fine too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select str_column, offset + 1 as offset, num
  from your_table, unnest(regexp_extract_all(str_column, r'\b([\d.]+)\b')) num with offset
)
pivot (min(num) as numerical_val for offset in (1,2,3))
```

if applied to sample data like in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great!

Comment: So I've been using this script and I'm not sure if this solution is producing consistent results. It returns a new table with 4 columns: ```str_column```, ```numerical_val_1```, ```numerical_val_2``` and ```numerical_val_3```. However, the number of rows in this new table are not equal to the number of rows in original table, ```your_table```. Also, I'd want the new extracted numerical columns to be concatenated to the original table. I tried using ```select A.*, offset + 1 ...``` with ```A``` being ```your_table``` and it returns a new table with less rows than in ```your_table```.

Comment: I think, you posted simplified data/schema sample in your question. so you've got the answer for it. Now, you obviously need to adopt above solution for your real data/use-case.  If you have problem with it - please post new question with all relevant details, samples and I will be happy to help further :o)

Comment: I created another post and included more details for a specific problem I'm trying to solve. Here is the link to my new question. I appreciate your help :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70976824/how-to-extract-all-numerical-values-from-a-string-column-in-a-big-query-table-an

Comment: i will check it later in a day :o)