# How to extract all numerical values from a string column in a big query table and insert them in new numerical columns?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table like `temp_table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `YOUR_DATASET.temp_table` (
  `F1` STRING,
  `F2` INT64,
  `F3` STRING,
);
```

And this table includes some data:

```
INSERT `YOUR_DATASET.temp_table` (F1, F2, F3)
VALUES('45FG67', 10, 'This stri98ng includes 10/15 numbers .9'),
      ('45FG67', 10, 'This string includes 100 and 0'),
      ('95pp7', 30, 'This string includes .8 and 1_number'),
      ('45FG67', 12, '45'),
      ('45FG67', 12,NULL),
      ('95pp7', 30, NULL),
      ('95pp7', 5, '10 & 54.2')
```

This would create the `temp_table` as:

```
SELECT * FROM `YOUR_DATASET.temp_table`
```

[image]

I would like to write a big query script to extract all numerical values in `F3` and append them as new numerical columns to `temp_table`. The number of new numerical columns should be equal to the maximum number of numerical values in `F3` . In this example table,`temp_table`, there should be 4 new numerical columns added to the table, because `F3` for row number 5 is `This stri98ng includes 10/15 numbers .9` and int includes 4 numerical values: 98, 10, 15, 0.9. As another example, the values for these 4 numerical columns for row number 6 would be 45, null, null, null.

Note, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945160/how-to-extract-all-including-int-and-float-numerical-values-in-a-string-column/70945308?noredirect=1#comment125446572_70945308) I asked a similar question. That solution works for that general question I asked there but doesn't work for the problem I described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below

```
select * from (
  select F1, F2, F3, offset + 1 as offset, num
  from your_table 
  left join unnest(regexp_extract_all(F3, r'([\d\.]+)')) num with offset
)
pivot (min(num) as numerical_val for offset in (1,2,3,4))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. How would you change the regex if there are negative values in ```F3``` too (for example, ```This string includes -2 and 8```?

Comment: use `regexp_extract_all(F3, r'(-?[\d\.]+)'))`